# Vuejs axios how to pass array with key?

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to post to my Laravel backend some data as 'offer' array:

That is how it looks in postman and works:
keys: **offer[title]**, **offer[description]**, **offer[author_user_id]**

now with axios I've tried something like:

```
 offer: {
         title: this.input.title,
         description: this.input.description,
         author_user_id: id,
         }
```

tried also with:
**[key=>val]** and for example **offer.title: value**, but also failed.

How it should looks like?

EDIT:

```
this.axios.post('http://api.wip/api/offer/store', {
                    offer: {
                        title: this.input.title,
                        description: this.input.description,
                        author_user_id: id,
                    },
                    category: 2
                }, {
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'X-Requested-With': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(function () {
                })
                .catch(function () {
                });
```

In my console I can see it's sent as:

```
{"offer":{"title":"asd","description":"asd","author_user_id":"2"},"category":2}:
```

I recive 500 error from server with response from Laravel that it expects data to be array.

```
"message": "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::create() must be of the type array, null given, called in D:\\wamp64\\www\\apitest\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Traits\\ForwardsCalls.php on line 23",
```

As I said it works with postman, but can't make this works from axios

Laravel controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request) {
        $offer = Offer::create($request->input('offer'));
        $offer->category()->sync($request->input('category'));
        $offer->save();

        return response()->json($offer);
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the actual axios function of yours? How do you add the payload and what is failing?

Comment: sure added more informations, I know how to fix it, but I'm wondering why it doesn't work like this. I could simply create different input names and then change my create() function, but that is much better way.

Comment: sure added Laravel controller

Answer (score 0):

Boussadjra Brahim is right the issue is in the backend But its caused by sending null values from the frontend so we have to take a look at frontend.

first thing is using {} meaning u are creating object , [] is array and laravel create method accept array only

the input is an array itself as u are accessing it keys with (dot) so why not just set offer to the whole array and then separate them in the backend ? like this

```
axios.post('http://api.wip/api/offer/store', {
                    offer:this.input,
                 author_user_id: id,
                    category: 2
                },
```

in your backend u can access them like :

```
$title = $request->offer['title'];
```

one last thing, when u are using create method the keys must be the same name as the column name in database or it will throw error!
hope it helps

Comment: I've fixed it by decoding json obj at backend and it worked, haven't tested your solution. You think I won't get any error this way? I think it need obj {} or array [], but while using array brackets I was getting error in response from vuejs :)